# Does Oracle Database support nested transactions?

Tags: oracle, transaction, oracle-21c

Does current version of Oracle Database (21c) support nested transactions?

I'm aware of Oracle DB supporting [savepoints](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/cncpt/transactions.html#GUID-55081904-2D79-430B-9E37-D4127F0BBF7D). However I'm looking for a way to make `COMMINT` not to write to disk for purpose of running tests.

Comment: All transactions will write to disk - think REDO and UNDO for sure, and possibly TEMP tablespace I/O as well - even if it isn't committed. There is no way to have a transaction not write to disk.

Answer (score 1):

"Oracle doesn't support nested transactions. If a transaction commits, it commits. That's why you generally don't want to commit (or rollback) a transaction in a stored procedure, that makes it difficult to reuse the procedure elsewhere if your transaction semantics differ." - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24506847/using-nested-transactions-in-oracle